# How can I properly set a minting price with Alchemy?

Tags: blockchain, nft, smart-contract-wallets, alchemy

I am having trouble establishing a mint price as Alchemy offers a too abstract coding practice for the smart contract part. I would like to know how I might set a minting price for my collection so that every time someone mints one of my NFTs, the money is allocated to my private Metamask account. I am sending the below code as something to work on:

```
     window.contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);//loadContract();

    //set up your Ethereum transaction
    const transactionParameters = {
        to: contractAddress, // Required except during contract publications.
        from: window.ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address.
        'data': window.contract.methods.mintNFT(window.ethereum.selectedAddress, tokenURI).encodeABI() //make call to NFT smart contract 
    };

    //sign transaction via Metamask
    try {
        const txHash = await window.ethereum
            .request({
                method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                params: [transactionParameters],
            });


// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721 {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;

  // Constants
  uint256 public constant TOTAL_SUPPLY = 10_000;
  uint256 public constant MINT_PRICE = 0.08 ether;

  Counters.Counter private currentTokenId;

  /// @dev Base token URI used as a prefix by tokenURI().
  string public baseTokenURI;

  constructor() ERC721("NFTTutorial", "NFT") {
    baseTokenURI = "";
  }

  function mintTo(address recipient) public payable returns (uint256) {
    uint256 tokenId = currentTokenId.current();
    require(tokenId < TOTAL_SUPPLY, "Max supply reached");
    require(msg.value == MINT_PRICE, "Transaction value did not equal the mint price");

    currentTokenId.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = currentTokenId.current();
    _safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
    return newItemId;
  }

  /// @dev Returns an URI for a given token ID
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseTokenURI;
  }

  /// @dev Sets the base token URI prefix.
  function setBaseTokenURI(string memory _baseTokenURI) public {
    baseTokenURI = _baseTokenURI;
  }
}

ABOVE YOU CAN FIND THE SOLIDITY CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting a mint price and collecting money, the way I've implemented it in the past is to:

1. Set the mint function on the NFT contract to be `payable`
2. Implement a `withdraw` function to manually take funds out of the contract and into my wallet

This is what it could look like (see the `mintOne`, `mintThree`, and `withdrawAll` functions):

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

/**
 * @title ChibiShinobis 
 * @author Albert Hu (@thatguyintech)
 * @dev Creates a contract to manage the Chibi Shinobis NFT project.
 */
contract ChibiShinobis is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {

    using Strings for uint256;

    string _baseTokenURI;
    string _contractURI;
    uint256 private _reserved = 888;
    uint256 private _price = 0.04 ether;

    // withdraw addresses on Rinkeby
    address t1 = 0x7E67aF7FF72cb87b7B0100cA8128F4673D185232;

    constructor(string memory baseURI, string memory contractDefaultURI) ERC721("Chibi Shinobis", "CHIBIS")  {
        setBaseURI(baseURI);
        setContractURI(contractDefaultURI);
    }

    // mint 1 chibi shinobi
    function mintOne() public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(supply + 1 + _reserved < 8889, "Only 8,888 Chibi Shinobis are available for hire in total. The limit has been reached.");
        require(msg.value >= _price, "The ether sent is not correct" );

        _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + 1);
    }

    // mint 3 chibi shinobis with a small discount
    function mintThree() public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(supply + 3 + _reserved < 8889, "Only 8,888 Chibi Shinobis are available for hire in total. The limit has been reached.");
        require(msg.value >= _price * 3 - 0.02, "The ether sent is not correct" );

        _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + 1);
        _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + 2);
        _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + 3);
    }

    function walletOfOwner(address _owner) public view returns(uint256[] memory) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);

        uint256[] memory tokensId = new uint256[](tokenCount);
        for(uint256 i; i < tokenCount; i++){
            tokensId[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokensId;
    }

    // Just in case Eth does some crazy stuff
    function setPrice(uint256 _newPrice) public onlyOwner() {
        _price = _newPrice;
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _price;
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _baseTokenURI;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory baseURI) public onlyOwner {
        _baseTokenURI = baseURI;
    }

    function setContractURI(string memory newContractURI) public onlyOwner {
        _contractURI = newContractURI;
    }

    function contractURI() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _contractURI;
    }

    // Withdraw funds accumulated in the contract to the desired address.
    function withdrawAll() public payable onlyOwner {
        require(payable(t1).send(address(this).balance));
    }
}
```

With this code as the smart contract implementation, on the frontend you'd call either the `mintOne` or `mintThree` functions for users to mint. Then after their mints are complete, this contract would be holding ETH. You as the owner of the contract can then call the `withdrawAll` function to take out the ETH.